# How Do i select this textbox for my selenium script?

Tags: python, selenium

Trying to learn python , this basic script is giving me problems.

```
import requests
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# load webpage

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/temperature/index.html")

# select text box

box = driver.find_element_by_id("f").click()  # this is throwing out problems
box.clear()
box.send_keys("22")
box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

box2 = driver.find_element_by_id("r")
print(box2.get_attribute("output"))
```

This should be straight forward. No idea why it isn't working.This is the element;

```
<input type="text" id="f" name="f" min="-459.67" tabindex="1" autofocus="" style="background-   color: white;">
```

There is another parent element ;
td class="math"
and I've tried calling this element by class and class_name to no avail.

When trying to find element by id "f"

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'clear'
```

When trying to find element by class "math"

```
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_class'
```

When trying to find element by class name "math"

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'clear'
```

Comment: Could you be more precise? What is the complete input, what are you getting as output and what are you expecting?

Comment: @alpha1554 edited main post to include error codes for various attempts. I am expecting the element(textbox) to be selected , clicked on , cleared if any text already in it (like suppose I want to run this in a loop to find various calculations) and finally , sent an enter command and grab the result from another textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in this line: `box = driver.find_element_by_id("f").click()`

Add `type(box)` in your code, and you can see it return the **NoneType** object. This is expected because you're trying to set `box` variable to not just the web element but to the **click** method. `.click()` method doesn't return anything, so you will need to separate the web element and method to fix the issue.

```
box = driver.find_element_by_id("f")
box.click()
box.clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to click the textbox it will throw exception because you cant click an input, you should `send_keys` to the input and after, click the button.
Also try to find the element with the relative path.

`box = driver.find_element_by_xpath( 'your relative path here')`

```
box.clear()
box.send_keys('your input')
```

Answer (score 0):

To wait for the element to be able to send keys to.

```
driver.get("https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/temperature/index.html")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
box = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "f")))
box.clear()
box.send_keys("22")
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```